# Remove \n l special characters from JSON String

Tags: java, json, string, replace

I am receiving a json like `"{\n \"brand\" : \"BMW\",\n   \"model\":\"X7\" \n}"`

However, I want to remove those escape characters and want to have the JSON like

```
 { "brand":"BMW", "model":"X7"}
```

I am using the below snippet to remove the characters from the json string.

```
String response = jsonString.replace("\\\n","").replace("\\","");
```

output for the above is

```
{n "brand":"BMW",n "model":"X7" n}
```

Not sure how to achieve my result.

Comment: Well, if you really receive such result, then you must let the other party know that they should fix their code. The string you receive is a JSON structure shoved into a JSON string. The question is, is this really what you receive?

Comment: The actual response is quite big. I am receiving the json as above string. But my downstream system expecting this as a normal json. I really cant use object mapper or any library, as the json could be anything.

Comment: Well, you could still map to a `Map<String, ...>` with `ObjectMapper` or any other library. I suggest you don't do the parsing yourself, but instead utilize a library which does the job for you.

Comment: Could you provide a little more context of what your actual response looks like?

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work as expected:

```
String response = jsonString.replaceAll("[\\n\\t ]", "");
```

This will remove all newlines, spaces and tab characters from a string.